Create CloudFomation stack only after the creation of another CloudFormation stack
I've created two CloudFormation templates.
The first one will create a DynamoDB table.
The second one will operate on the DynamoDB table created.
The resources need to be on separate stacks because the second stack can be deleted and recreated multiple times.
As you can see, I need the first stack to be created first and, only after that, create the second one.
But, from my node aplication, I have no idea how can I do that. If I just send the requests to CloudFormation, they will be created in an arbitrary order.
How can I solve this problem?
